# How to show "leave a reply" form in the wordpress twentyeleven theme

Tags: wordpress

I am using twentyeleven theme for my wordpress application. But after clicking on any post its displaying post details, but not showing "leave a reply" form. Its saying "Comments are closed". I have used  comments_template( '', true ) in the single.php file, but still "leave a reply" is not showing.
Please any one help me!!!

Thanks
Shama Kausar

Comment: Did you select Allow comments option on post page?

Comment: yes I selected comments option on post page, but still its not coming.

Comment: did you turn on comments from  settings > Discussion ?

Comment: Yes, I checked under 'Default article settings' and 'Other comment settings' in settings > Discussion

Answer (score 0):

i hope you haven't used any plugin to disable comments.? Such issues arise after restricting comments thru plugin in setting. Just remove if you have installed one or you can , just check the settings in settings area from dashboard. If not them go to wrodpress.org and you will find complete databse over there.

P.S
Make sure you have upgraded to word press 3.6